# How can i give negative value for variable?

Tags: php

I am trying to make some function but, i am getting white page result when i put -ve value for `$variable`. Look this variable has -ve value : `$long_total_profit_loss = "-900";`

```
$long_total_profit_loss = "-900";
$short_sell_total_profit_loss = "-600";

//CONCLUTION
if(($long_total_profit_loss > $short_sell_total_profit_loss) && ($long_total_profit_loss>0)){

    echo "long has higher in profit";
}elseif (($long_total_profit_loss > $short_sell_total_profit_loss) && ($long_total_profit_loss < 0)){

    echo "long has higher loss";
}elseif (($long_total_profit_loss < $short_sell_total_profit_loss) && ($long_total_profit_loss > 0)){

    echo "short has higher in profit";
}
elseif (($long_total_profit_loss > $short_sell_total_profit_loss) && ($long_total_profit_loss < 0)){

    echo "short has higher loss";
}
```

Comment: them are strings not numbers

Comment: Welcome. You're assigning strings, `$long_total_profit_loss = "-900"`. Remove the `"`

Comment: Non of those if statements evaluate to true, hence no output

Comment: and note that none echo will be triggered, you need another `elseif` statement: `elseif(($long_total_profit_loss < $short_sell_total_profit_loss) && ($long_total_profit_loss < 0)){`

Comment: *"i am getting white page result"* - Are you getting an error?  Turn on error reporting, check your PHP error logs, etc.  Alternatively, if you're just getting no output, well, the only output you're showing is entirely within conditional statements.  When none of those conditions are met, what output do you *expect* and *why*?  When your code logically produces no output, a "white page" is a successful result.

Comment: This is one of the rare moments where nested if clauses would lead to a better readability (and shorter code).

Comment: @KINNARI, you are getting a white page because none of the clauses will ever happen like this. -900 is a smaller number than -600. Quotes are not the problem here.

Comment: i removed `"` like : `$long_total_profit_loss = -900;` but till not working @kerbholz

Comment: -900 is smaller number than -600? really? @Rafael

Comment: Your second and last `elseif` are the same. Change the last one from `>` to `<`. And yes, -900 is smaller than -600.

Comment: @David you are absolute right.

Comment: Sorry for the not very intuitive assumption on my side @KINNARI, some logic problems shouldn't be enough to assume that. My mistake.

Comment: no problem, I will try.. thanks so much @Rafael

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd recommend to structure your conditions differently (with nested if statements), which will give you a better overview and readability so you can't forget a special situation.

```
$long_total_profit_loss = -900;
$short_sell_total_profit_loss = -600;

if($long_total_profit_loss > $short_sell_total_profit_loss) {
   if($long_total_profit_loss > 0) {
     echo "long has higher in profit";
   }
   else { // $long_total_profit_loss<0 or =0
     echo "short has higher loss";
   }
}
else { // $long_total_profit_loss < $short_sell_total_profit_loss or equal
   if($short_sell_total_profit_loss > 0) {
      echo "short has higher in profit";
   }
   else {  // $short_sell_total_profit_loss<0 or =0
      echo "long has higher loss";
   }
}

// output: short has higher loss
```

You could/should extend this to capture the case when those values are equal to each other and equal to 0.

*EDIT*
swapped wording of "*short* has higher loss" and "*long* has higher loss", which makes more sense, thanks to @Rafael

Comment: I was hoping you'd expend on your comment and here we go, nice one, much more readable

Comment: How come long would have a higher loss than short if $long would be bigger than $short?

Comment: I don't know. tbh I just copied the concluding wording from the OP, as only the logic was the problem (with one missing possibility).

Comment: I fixed it on my answer, please update your answer with it so the OP can choose yours.

Comment: @Jeff This is giving wrong result when, '$long_total_profit_loss = -2100;` & `$short_sell_total_profit_loss = 15900;` OUTPUT is : long has higher loss @Rafael ... result should be Short has higher profit

Comment: Fixed. Check it again please. @Jeff, another update, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome.
The main problem is that none of that statements evaluate to true. (so you'll never echo anything)
You missed one (-900 is smaller than -600) :

```
elseif(($long_total_profit_loss < $short_sell_total_profit_loss) && ($long_total_profit_loss < 0)){
    echo "your evalutation";   
}
```

As @Dale pointed out in the comments

> use strings isn't the issue, php (rightly or wrongly) will do the
>   conversion for you

I still suggest to declare those variables as numbers.
The final piece of code should be something like this:

```
<?php
$long_total_profit_loss = -900;
        $short_sell_total_profit_loss = -600;

        //CONCLUTION
        if(($long_total_profit_loss > $short_sell_total_profit_loss) && ($long_total_profit_loss>0)){

            echo "long has higher in profit";
        }elseif (($long_total_profit_loss > $short_sell_total_profit_loss) && ($long_total_profit_loss < 0)){

            echo "long has higher loss";
        }elseif (($long_total_profit_loss < $short_sell_total_profit_loss) && ($long_total_profit_loss > 0)){

            echo "short has higher in profit";
        }elseif(($long_total_profit_loss < $short_sell_total_profit_loss) && ($long_total_profit_loss < 0)){

                        echo "your evalutation";

        }
```

Comment: hello @Nicolò Cozzani actually, i want to write : If long_total_profit_loss > long_total_profit_loss  AND CHECK ALSO IF ITS more than 0 (+ve)... then echo""

Comment: You can add all the `if statements` that you want. Simply, in this case, none of them was evaluated to true.

Answer (score 1):

From what I can gather, you haven't taken into account a couple of situations.

```
<?php

$long_total_profit_loss = "-900";
$short_sell_total_profit_loss = "-600";

//CONCLUTION
if (($long_total_profit_loss > $short_sell_total_profit_loss) && ($long_total_profit_loss > 0)) {

    echo "long has higher in profit";
} elseif (($long_total_profit_loss > $short_sell_total_profit_loss) && ($long_total_profit_loss < 0)) {

    echo "long has higher loss";
} elseif (($long_total_profit_loss < $short_sell_total_profit_loss) && ($long_total_profit_loss > 0)) {

    echo "short has higher in profit";
} elseif (($long_total_profit_loss > $short_sell_total_profit_loss) && ($long_total_profit_loss < 0)) {

    echo "short has higher loss";
} else {
    echo "Whoops I didn't think about this one!";
}
```

I have only added an extra else to catch anything you haven't considered, I hope you can take this and run with it

Answer (score 1):

I'm gonna write an answer because I see people missing the point of the information displayed.

```
$long_total_profit_loss = -900;
$short_sell_total_profit_loss = -600;
```

In this case, the $long is a smaller number than $short, which means that if you want to know:

- If $long would have a higher profit than $short, then $long has to be bigger than $short (this[your] statement is *correct*):

  `if ($long... > $short... && $long > 0) echo 'Long has higher profit than short`
- If $long would have a higher loss than $short, then $long has to be smaller than $short (this[your] statement is **incorrect**):

  `if ($long... < $short...) echo 'Long has higher loss than short`
- If $short would have a higher profit than $long, then $short has to be bigger than $long (this[your] statement is *correct*):

  `if ($long... < $short... && $short > 0) echo 'Short has higher profit than long`
- (And finally) If $short would have a higher loss than $long, then $short has to be smaller than $long (this[your] statement is *correct*):

  `if ($long... > $short...) echo 'Short has higher loss than long`

The main thing here is that:

`Short has higher loss than long` **is equivalent** to `Long has higher profit than short` in your code.

Both of them are comparing to smaller than **zero** so the last cause in the queue will never be triggered anyway. The one asking for a profit should have the condition *bigger than* zero.

And the last thing, you're right, I'm sure you know that -900 is smaller than -600, but it didn't look like that looking at your second statement. Sorry. :)

**[Edit]**

@Jeff has a point, profit has everything to do with bigger than zero.

**[Edit2]**

Jeff mantained the mistake you have in your code, though his solution has the best approach/readability IMO.

I fixed here, expecting he will update his answer so you can choose his (NOT MINE).

```
$long_total_profit_loss = -900;
$short_sell_total_profit_loss = -600;

if($long_total_profit_loss > $short_sell_total_profit_loss) {
   if($long_total_profit_loss > 0) {
     echo "long has higher in profit";
   } else { // $long_total_profit_loss<0 or =0
     echo "short has higher loss";
   }
}
else { // $long_total_profit_loss < $short_sell_total_profit_loss or equal
   if($short_sell_total_profit_loss > 0) {
      echo "short has higher in profit";
   } else {  // $long_total_profit_loss<0 or =0
      echo "long has higher loss";
   }
}
```

Tested here: https://3v4l.org/PY0P2

Comment: _"I ignored the smaller than zero conditions"_ - that's the difference between "profit" and "loss", isn't it?

Comment: Sure, but both variables are negative values, what's the profit in it? Though it's worthy to consider.

Comment: _"both variables are negative values"_ - yes, now. They are variables, so could be positive (what would indicate a profit then)

Comment: its not in profit... question is, which variable has higher loss?

Comment: suppose, value are `$long_total_profit_loss = -900;`
`$short_sell_total_profit_loss = 600;` its should respect first higher value onlly... -900 higher value.

Comment: I updated my answer using @Jeff `s approach, but with a correction, check it. When he updates his answer, choose his.

Comment: This is giving wrong result:  `$long_total_profit_loss = -2100;` & 
           `$short_sell_total_profit_loss = 15900;`  OUTPUT is : long has higher loss @Rafael ... result should be Short has higher profit

Comment: Fixed. Check my answer again. Forgot to add $short to the second test intead of $long